# Issues while sending raw transaction for calling smart contract methods?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, etherscan, infura

```
 let provider_url = 
"https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/d5bca90ec3084aee8abd468fdf876a11";

this.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(provider_url);
window.web3_ = new Web3(this.web3Provider);

let account = "0x25bA673A96acadD7A02f4c5834Ba80C1AF6b7758";

          let nonce = window.web3_.toHex(window.web3_.eth.getTransactionCount(account));

          let myPrivateKey = "****";

          let privateKey = new Buffer(myPrivateKey, "hex");
          let functionName = "markAttendance";
          let types = ["address", "uint", "uint256"];
          let args = [attendeeAddress, opinion, date];
          let fullName = functionName + "(" + types.join() + ")";
          let signature = CryptoJS.SHA3(fullName, {outputLength: 256}).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex).slice(0, 8);
          let dataHex = signature + coder.encodeParams(types, args);
          let data = "0x" + dataHex;
          // let nonce = web3.toHex();
          let gasPrice = window.web3_.toHex(20000000000); // 20 Gwei
          let gasLimitHex = window.web3_.toHex(4700000);

          let rawTx = {
            'nonce': nonce,
            'gasPrice': gasPrice,
            'gasLimit': gasLimitHex,
            'from': account,
            'to': '0xf77c958bdffee94c3f53eb763cffd646cde336d9', 
            'data': data,
            'value': window.web3_.toHex(window.web3_.toWei("0.5", "ether")),
          }
          let tx = new Tx(rawTx);
          tx.sign(privateKey);
          tx.serialize();
          console.log(tx.validate());
          let serializedTx = '0x' + tx.serialize().toString('hex');
          console.log(serializedTx);
window.web3_.eth.sendRawTransaction(serializedTx, function (err, txHash) {
  console.log(err, txHash)
})
```

**Contract**

```
contract MarkAttendance {

struct AttendeeDetails {
    address attendance_giver;
    address attendee;
    uint attendance_opinion;
    uint256 timestamp;
    uint256 date_of_attendance;
}

//mapping of structure  for storing the attendeeDetails
mapping(uint => AttendeeDetails) public attendeeDetails;
uint public attendeeDetailsCount;

function markAttendance(address _attendee, uint _attendance_opinion, uint256 _date) public {
    attendeeDetailsCount ++;
    attendeeDetails[attendeeDetailsCount] = AttendeeDetails(msg.sender, _attendee, _attendance_opinion, now, _date);
    }
}
```

I am getting TXHASH but transaction is getting cancelled every time . what might be the issue i am doing ? can anyone suggest me any solution for this .

It works fine if I call the method from truffle console. I get a successful transaction receipt .

[please find the screenshot](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blockshorts-app.appspot.com/o/Screen%20Shot%202018-12-07%20at%206.12.43%20PM.png?alt=media&token=c347be92-21fc-469d-9145-2ec5ed21ccea)

Comment: The transaction was reverted. To know why, you'd have to look at the code for the contract.

Comment: Does it work if you send it as normal transaction ? I.e. let node sign it instead of signing it on client side ?  If that works, it can be a next step for troubleshooting.  Since there is a "revert", it might fail as normal transaction as well.

Comment: You provided contract account in `rawTx` is to:`0x7145dc9549f548bef6bb2916e063cc0404d2e8d9` and your actually contract address is `0x7145dc9549f548bEF6BB2916e063CC0404d2E8d8`.  there is slight change in last character `9` from `8`. correct it.

Comment: @MaheshRajput Although that certainly looks like an issue, the transaction in the screenshot seems to going to the correct address: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xb1ba1053c394b9d321e63ff53e2076c4c6d71f7d286dd2ac9e264697ec1fc8d6.

Comment: Yes @smarx I agree with you, but I am just asking to **sibabrat** to correct that change in question so anyone doesn't west their time to find another error by this code.

Comment: The private key also doesn't match the from address.

Comment: @MaheshRajput Ok I have corrected the question.

Comment: @smarx the contract is very simple Please look into the question again I have added the contract code.

Comment: @ShamitVerma I am using infura for this matter .

Comment: change fromaccount with account

Comment: Hey @sibabrat swain, why are you sending `0.5 ether` to call this function? not need of that just remove `value` part from rawTx and then try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function selector calculation is incorrect. You're using `"uint"` instead of `"uint256"`. (The former is an alias for the latter, but the latter should always be used when calculating a function selector.)

Change this line:

```
let types = ["address", "uint", "uint256"];
```

to this:

```
let types = ["address", "uint256", "uint256"];
```

**EDIT**

You're also attaching ether to the transaction, but the function you're calling is not `payable` so it won't accept ether. To fix this, drop the `value: ...` line.

Comment: It didn't work. Even I have changed the uint to uint256 in contract and deployed once again . 

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xad7de143b2b5486f96eefff4526feb4196a9d0952b14610d725b6b439ab5b182
but works fine with console 
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blockshorts-app.appspot.com/o/Screen%20Shot%202018-12-08%20at%201.58.50%20PM.png?alt=media&token=c76fd8ac-80d7-4429-aeee-a3559b41eca7

Comment: You also need to fix the issue @MaheshRajput pointed out, which is that you're attaching ether when calling a non-`payable` function.