# Call contract method via raw transaction in python

Tags: erc-20, mining, infura, python

From what I've read online I can't call the method I want to in python using

`contract.functions.myfunc(param1,param2`

becaues infura doens't support these types of transactions.

So instead I want to run this command (still in python) as a raw transaction using the `Eth.sendRawTransaction` function in `Web3.py` but it's not clear to me how I would do this. [This](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/63805/issues-while-sending-raw-transaction-for-calling-smart-contract-methods) example seems to be pretty close but I'm in python, not solidity not go-ethereum.

Guidance would be appreciated!